# cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, cmd, error-code

I'm trying to use phonegap to make an android app, but it shows me this:

```
    c:\Users\sshewale\Desktop\phone gap\hello>phonegap platform add android
    npm
     http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android
    
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android
    
    Adding android project...
    
    Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
        at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\sshewale\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
    \phonegap\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.j
    s:134:23)
        at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:107:17)
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1072:12)
        at child_process.js:1144:20
        at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

UPDATE: It Moved A Bit Ahead But Now It Shows This:

```
        C:\Users\sshewale\hi>cordova platform add android
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/-/cordova-android-4.0.2.
    tgz
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/-/cordova-android-4.0.2.
    tgz
    Adding android project...
    Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
        at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\sshewale\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
    \cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:134:23)
        at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:107:17)
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1072:12)
        at child_process.js:1144:20
        at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
    
    C:\Users\sshewale\hi>
```

I'm not sure why this is happening, I don't remember changing any setting from the defaults.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please add **C:\Windows\System32** in your PATH variable

Comment: My error is In the output window when I build from selecting the device tab.  Any advice on how exactly do I add that to the PATH variable?

Answer (score 1):

In a Windows environment:
If you have already installed `cordova`, do the following:

1. `npm uninstall cordova -g` or `npm uninstall -g cordova`
2. Delete folder `.cordova`
3. Right click your PC icon >> Properties
4. Control Panel >> Advanced System Properties >> Environment Variables...
5. Define C:\Windows\System32 as a *System Variable*(Bottom Window) ie SYSTEM_HOME
6. Then define %SYSTEM_HOME% in the Server Variables (Top Window)
7. BEFORE REINSTALLING `cordova` run the `**** platform add android`  command
8. THEN run `npm install -g cordova` or `npm install cordova -g`

I've been working with `ionic@beta` and the `...platform add ...` relies heavily on `cordova` so it is recommended to add the platforms BEFORE initiating `cordova` to minimize conflict.

Hope this helps.
`****` = `phonegap` or `ionic`

Answer (score 1):

Installation of CORDOVA

1. Install node
2. open CMD
3. node -v       for checking version installed
4. npm -v        for checking version installed
5. Npm install -g cordova
6. After Insatalling Android SDK
7. Open SDK manager (Download API LEVEL 23 & 24 only)
8. Set the Environment Variables of Android SDK:-
   To add the SDK Tools to the PATH, open the Control Panel, click System and Security, click System, click Change settings, click the Advanced tab, then click the Environment Variables button.

   In the list User variables select PATH and click the Edit button.

   At the end of the field Variable value, add a semicolon followed by the path to the tools and platform-tools directores of the Android SDK install. Here is an example of what to add (note that there are two paths in one line, separated by a semicolon):

   ;C:\Users\anshu\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools;C:\Users\anshu\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools

   You can prepare the path in a text editor, copy it and paste at the end of the input field. Click the OK button when done.
   Click the OK button again to close the Environment Variables window.

   Now test the install. Close any open command windows, open a new command window and type:

   adb version
   This should display the version of the Android Debug Bridge.
9. Navigate to C:>cd Nodespace\Android
10. Type >>cordova create Test com.anshu.test Test
11. Type >>cd Test
12. Type >>cordova platform add android
13. Type >>cordova compile android

After Connecting Android Device in Debugging Mode to Your System VIA USB

14. Type>>cordova run

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\Users\VinexN207>cordova platform add android
Error: Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.

C:\Users\VinexN207>cd C:\Project\java_script\nShop

C:\Project\java_script\nShop>cordova platform add android
Error: Platform android already added.

C:\Project\java_script\nShop>cordova platforms ls
Installed platforms: android 5.1.1
Available platforms: amazon-fireos, blackberry10, browser, firefoxos, webos, win
dows, windows8, wp8

C:\Project\java_script\nShop>cordova platform add ios
WARNING: Applications for platform ios can not be built on this OS - win32.
Adding ios project...
iOS project created with cordova-ios@4.0.1
Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for ios

C:\Project\java_script\nShop>cordova platforms ls
Installed platforms: android 5.1.1, ios 4.0.1
Available platforms: amazon-fireos, blackberry10, browser, firefoxos, webos, win
dows, windows8, wp8

C:\Project\java_script\nShop>
```

Yes, it works after adding path. Probably it works, because it doesn't write it `Installed platforms: android-broken`.

Answer (score -2):

Try to follow these steps:

- run

  ```
  npm uninstall cordova -g
  ```
- delete the folder `C:\Users\your-name.cordova`
- reinstall the cordova: npm install cordova -g
- go to the project folder and try again

  ```
  cordova platform add android
  ```