# Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT

Tags: android, cordova

I have referred many result regarding this error. But nothing helps me to solve this problem. Initially when i create a project by using the create command am getting following message in command prompt.

```
Using detached cordova-create
Creating a new cordova project.
```

I don't know why am getting `Using detached cordova-create` this message. But project is created and when i try to add platform for android am getting following error.

```
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-whitelist':Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
```

I have listed the plugins using `cordova plugin ls`and `cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.0 "Whitelist"` is available. I don't know why this problem occurred. Just I want to learn cordova. But I can't move further without fixing this issue.

Please can someone help me to solve this problems.

Here are some links which i referred.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23422961/cordova-cannot-add-android-failed-with-exit-code-enoent
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31761464/cmd-command-failed-with-exit-code-enoent
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31089647/cordova-error-code-1-for-command-command-failed-for
```

Comment: What platforms, if any, do you have installed (`cordova platform ls`)?

Comment: @KerriShotts Its working fine when i downgrade the cordova version. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[This is to help others with different case but same error]

In my case, the error showed up when I ran `cordova requirements`. The issue was I had to add `$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools` to the path and not `$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`

So I added this in the .bashrc file

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT='/home/your_username/Android/Sdk'

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/lib/x86_64
```

And then it ran fine.

Reference for Mac OS:

https://gist.github.com/kristopherjohnson/7568583