# ionic run android Command displays the following error:

Tags: android, angular, ionic2, android-studio-2.3

I have set the environment variable path to Android sdk destination.
the device is connected with the usb and the latest usb drivers have been installed.

`C:\Users\Lenovo\walkin1>adb devices
List of devices attached
ZY2225FT8N      device`

```
> ionic-hello-world@ ionic:build C:\Users\Lenovo\walkin1
> ionic-app-scripts build

[08:55:43]  ionic-app-scripts 1.1.4
[08:55:43]  build dev started ...
[08:55:43]  clean started ...
[08:55:43]  clean finished in 33 ms
[08:55:43]  copy started ...
[08:55:43]  transpile started ...
[08:56:06]  transpile finished in 22.58 s
[08:56:06]  preprocess started ...
[08:56:06]  preprocess finished in 2 ms
[08:56:06]  webpack started ...
[08:56:07]  copy finished in 23.29 s
[08:56:55]  webpack finished in 49.31 s
[08:56:55]  sass started ...
[08:57:00]  sass finished in 4.50 s
[08:57:00]  postprocess started ...
[08:57:00]  postprocess finished in 1 ms
[08:57:00]  lint started ...
[08:57:00]  build dev finished in 76.53 s
[08:57:31]  lint finished in 31.48 s
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk

Subproject Path: CordovaLib

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
```

Here is my ionic info output:
`C:\Users\Lenovo\walkin1>ionic info
Your system information:
 ordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic Framework Version: 2.2.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.1.4
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 10
Node Version: v6.9.5
Xcode version: Not installed`

Performed the following tasks:
1.)`npm uninstall cordova -g or npm uninstall -g`
2.)cordovaDelete folder .cordova
3.)Right click on PC icon >> Properties
Control Panel >> Advanced System Properties >> Environment Variables...
Define C:\Windows\System32 as a System Variable(Bottom Window) ie SYSTEM_HOME
Then define %SYSTEM_HOME% in the Server Variables (Top Window)
THEN run `npm install -g cordova or npm install cordova -g`
Then run `ionic add platform android`
o/p:`platform android already added`

Comment: can you also add output of `ionic info`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31761464/cmd-command-failed-with-exit-code-enoent check this..

Comment: Checked the link...

Comment: checked the link but none is working...