# Cordova Build Android failed with exit code ENOENT

Tags: android, windows, cordova, npm, phonegap-build

I am beginner with the cordova, I followed all the step mentioned in **Create your first Cordova app** document.

I am able to satisfy all the android requirements on the windows machine.

[image: cordova android requirements]

But I am not able to run the **Cordova build android** command. I am getting following error

[image: cordova build]

For solution, I also referred [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31761464/cmd-command-failed-with-exit-code-enoent) but my problem didn't solve

Comment: check this:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/33280304/4188585

Comment: Please add C:\Windows\System32 in your PATH variable

Comment: @Gaurab,
 After referring to the above link, I have added the above path to PATH variable still I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Is there any way to update the android sdk through command prompt.

Comment: see the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update android sdk through command line:

Go to folder **android-sdk\tools\bin** and run the command:

**List installed and available packages**

```
sdkmanager --list
```

**Install packages**

```
sdkmanager packages [options]
```

**For example, to get adb and fastboot, install the latest platform tools:**

```
sdkmanager "platforms;android-25"
```

**Usage:**

```
  sdkmanager --update [<common args>]
  sdkmanager --list [<common args>]
  sdkmanager [--uninstall] [<common args>] \
    [--package_file <package-file>] [<packages>...]

In its first form, installs, or uninstalls, or updates packages.
    <package> is a sdk-style path (e.g. "build-tools;23.0.0" or
             "platforms;android-23").
    <package-file> is a text file where each line is a sdk-style path
                   of a package to install or uninstall.
    Multiple --package_file arguments may be specified in combination
     with explicit paths.
In its second form (with --update), currently installed packages are
    updated to the latest version.
In its third form, all installed and available packages are printed out.
```

Reference: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html