# Jenkins fails Cordova Android build

Tags: android, cordova, jenkins

I have been struggling with getting this to work from Jenkins for weeks and I know it's got to be something simple.

I am able to log onto the build machine via Remote Desktop and do the build just fine running

```
npm run build:android
```

which in turn calls

```
webpack && cordova build android --verbose.
```

This is the same command I'm using from Jenkins. My Jenkins build step is to run the following Windows Batch Commands:

```
call npm install
call npm run build:android
```

**The error**

This is the error that I get when it is run from Jenkins:

```
17:30:26 ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\build\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
17:30:26 JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144
17:30:26 Running command: cmd "/s /c ""C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-3.2\bin\gradle.bat" -p C:\Jenkins\workspace\gm-mobile-android-build\platforms\android wrapper -b C:\Jenkins\workspace\gm-mobile-android-build\platforms\android\wrapper.gradle""
17:30:26 Command finished with error code ENOENT: cmd /s /c ""C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-3.2\bin\gradle.bat" -p C:\Jenkins\workspace\gm-mobile-android-build\platforms\android wrapper -b C:\Jenkins\workspace\gm-mobile-android-build\platforms\android\wrapper.gradle"
17:30:26 Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
```

Unfortunately I haven't been able to figure out much from this error message.
I presumed it could have something to do with permission but I can run the same command fine with the same user via Remote Desktop.

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to add C:\Windows\System32 to the PATH variable specified for this machine in Jenkins.

Found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33280304/2449330